# Purpose of making a question a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I know community wiki answers can be edited to be more correct and accurate.

But I don't know how could community contribute to a question?

I mean, the question is the questioner's question and how could community improve it?

The only reason I've seen till now is to escape from downvotes.

So why make a question community wiki?

Comment: You can't make a question community wiki by yourself.

Answer (score 8):

The usual reason to make a *question* CW is simply to emphasize that it exists *purely* as a wiki: no non-wiki answers allowed, just edit the one(s) already there.

One of the best (and oldest) examples of this are the [meta faq topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). It's *very* rare that more than one answer is even necessary, and in *all* cases it's essential that the answer(s) be kept up to date long after the original authors are gone: as a result, one of the rules for turning a question into an official meta faq is that it must be made CW first.

The wisdom of establishing this rule has been demonstrated time and time again, as changes to the system necessitated *massive* re-writes of existing topics. Instead of an impenetrable mess of obsolete answers (with the most current information ranked *lowest*) we have in most cases a single, up-to-date answer.

On the main sites, this is much more rare. However, several communities *have* made use of similar techniques in order to handle similarly-common questions requiring extensive input from many different people.

To prevent abuse, making a *question* Community Wiki requires the assistance of a moderator.

#### See also:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
- [The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)
- [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/)