# Is posting an solution in a question bad practice?

Tags: discussion

Sorry about the title, but I didn't know how else to word it.

What I mean by this is, I posted a question ([This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176560/string-format-of-string-stored-int), probably opening a can of worms onto myself) and after a fair bit of back and forth in the comments, [Fruchtzwerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5235574/fruchtzwerg) posted a great answer. It solved the issue I was having, but created another which is directly related to the problem at hand. (I am not going to go into what and why the problem occurred here)

Being that this was the first time I had used a `Converter` I spent the next couple of hours reverse engineering the answer so I could make a work around to fix the issue it created.

My dilemma is that I know an answer should be posted as an answer, but due to most of the work being done by the user who created the answer to my problem, it does not feel right to post one. And on the other hand, this site is a resource for other users, so the more information the better and how ever unlikely it may be, someone else may also have the same problem I had, so I feel obligated to post the solution I cam up with.

**So, what is the accepted practice here in the situation, how should I have handled this?**

Edit:
I am going to edit my linked question as stated in the answer to this question and I should leave what I was talking about. This is a screen shot of what I am taking out.

[image]

Comment: You could post it as a proper answer, but make it community wiki so you wouldn't get reputation from somebody else's work. See also [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343086/why-would-you-mark-an-answer-as-community-wiki).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for showing me that, I made it a community wiki, Thanks everyone, that solves my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is posting an solution in a question bad practice?

Yes it's bad practice. You already understand that this is a question and answer site with one major goal being that it should be easy for programmers with a similar problem to find your question, find the answers, and then get help by studying the answers. This means that the *answers must be in the answers section* and not the questions section, so that they are consistently placed and easy to find, else your answer may be overlooked. If you want to answer your own question, then post a new answer to the question.

> ... but due to most of the work being done by the user who created the answer to my problem, it does not feel right to post one.

Egos, and length of work shouldn't matter, but rather it's all about the quality of the questions and their answers, and how useful this site is for all who come.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post and posted it as an answer. I also edited this threads question to leave some context for other users. Thanks.