# Post final solution in question

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I have [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458422/query-maximum-webcam-resolution-in-opencv) where the answer I accepted was perfect but in a different programming language (Python, I required C++).

Although the conversion is quite simple if you know both languages and OpenCV, I thought it may be useful for somebody else to have the C++ implementation. I then edited the question to post the final solution I used (I thought it was too long for a comment).

The thing is that now (some months later and after knowing a bit more about how SO works), I feel like I'm not being fair with the user who answered my question; maybe people reach the question, see the solution there and don't up vote the accepted answer.

What should I do, what is considered a good practice? Keep the adapted solution in the question? Post it as a new answer leaving accepted the original one in Python? Revert the edit in the question and leave the answer in Python only?

**UPDATE**

I've read [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343578/is-posting-an-solution-in-a-question-bad-practice) with a similar question, but in that one the final answer was got from a comment, so there is less visibily of the answer and the user who posted the comment couldn't receive any rep for it.

In this case *there is an answer* that I found almost perfect with the difference of the language, so I published the final (C++) solution in the question.

Comment: A python answer to a c++ question is not an answer.  Not usually anyway.  Just add the solution yourself.  Not in the question, in a proper post below the line.  Whether you mark it as the answer is up to you, be sure to credit the poster for the solution with a link to his profile and a link to his post.

Comment: @veve probably, I read that before posting... I wanted to consider the fact that it was a variation of an actual answer, not a comment... thanks!

Comment: "In this case there is an answer that I found almost perfect with the difference of the language, so I published the final (C++) solution in the question." please don't do this.

Comment: @Veve thanks, I've already edited the question to remove the solution and published as a new answer.