# When is it justified to Community Wiki your own answers?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

This is a question that's been on my mind for *quite* a while, especially in light of a particular user's habit of repeatedly Community Wiki'ing their own answers.

Out of their 10 most recent answers, five of them have been marked as Community Wikis: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734643/why-math-sin1-works-and-math-sin1-not/50734700#50734700), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730648/4909087), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50663745/4909087), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632758/4909087), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615634/4909087). If you go further down, you find more. Additionally, running this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150218/my-community-wikis) tells me they have CW'd a total of **274** of their own answers.

Jeff Atwood explicitly mentioned once that Community Wikis were to be used only sparingly under situations where the answer is a constructive, collaborate effort from the community. But not one of the 5 answers I've listed above (and most others besides them) have been edited/touched by any user besides the user who wrote the answer. They've also resisted edits to their answers in the past.

I raised a flag on one of these answers to request that the CW be rolled back, but the flag was declined effectively stating that the request was not worth the moderator's time. So, I ask. Are these markings valid? If not, what is the right thing to do when you come across actions taken by a user whose intentions are not 100% clear?

Comment: Maybe it is because they are sick of the down votes that are casted for answering at all...

Comment: I would say forget Atwood, this is the welcoming era we are in. What exactly is the harm done by making a post CW? Except that they abstain from the reputation gain/loss?

Comment: @rene: No harm done, but if the sentence "They've also resisted edits to their answers in the past." is true of their CW answers, then they're misusing the feature by misleading others into thinking that their answers are collaborative when they're not.

Comment: @rene I don't get the argument behind that. If you are answering, you should be prepared to accept the rep gain/loss thereof...

Comment: @BoltClock If you remember, there was once a situation where I'd posted an answer as a CW which you rolled back at your own discretion because "there was no point in the CW". If there being "no point" is a legitimate reason for _not_ making an answer CW (or rolling it back), then I think we should look into this more closely.

Comment: @coldspeed: Yeah, that was pretty recent too. I still maintain that non-CW should be the default and CW should be used only sparingly for its intended purpose - and unlike what rene might suggest, I don't need Jeff's approval to maintain that stance. I'm hoping either there's more to this than meets the eye, or the user really is just embracing the spirit of CW for their selected answers, and I've pinged the user about it.

Comment: [They've also resisted edits to their answers in the past](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/860411) with 9 rollbacks on CW answers and 34 overall on their own answers that is not a huge signal. The third resultset in that query offers better targets.

Comment: I personally routinely use CW for answers to bountied questions.  I'm thoroughly uninterested in the kind of strategic voting that is common with such questions, with CW I don't even see them.  I would imagine that a mod isn't all that thrilled about DVs from vengeful users either.  Legitimate reason enough.

Comment: I answered many answers as CW, letting them open for improvements that I didn't feel the need to bring myself, especially on very simple questions. I stopped because this seems to bring some hate on my answers from people willing to gain rep from those questions. That was long before Ry- (then Minitech) started to do it himself and I know we chatted a little about that.

Comment: @Hans if you post a CW answer to a bounty question, do you still get the bounty?

Comment: CW does not affect stuff like badges and bounty awards, only edits and up/down votes.

Comment: @HansPassant Nitpick: it affects tag score and, as a consequence, tag badges.

Comment: Related: [*Why would you mark an answer as Community Wiki?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343086/2751851)

Comment: As the answers say, the owner can make them CW if they want to. Historically, they're easy to make CW, but hard to undo. However, I'm hawkish on CW. Here's my thinking: I tend to curate my best answers because I get notifications. CW answers give me few/no notifications. Making answers CW seems to usually result in making no-one (as opposed to everyone) responsible for the content. If an answerer (not just random community members) asks me to remove CW, and it hasn't been treated like a CW (substantial edits by other editors) I'm usually more than happy to.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Short answer: whenever you want. If it's your answer, you have complete autonomy as to whether it's CW or not. Just keep in mind, by marking it CW **you voluntarily cede some amount of ownership to the community** - you won't be given full credit for the answer and you will allow a good many more people to make edits without approval. That's the deal; whether or not those terms are justified is a personal decision.

Now... It gets more complicated for *questions*: CW questions have a long and complicated history, which you can find summarized in the blog post [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/22/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). But for answers, it's all much simpler:

[image: Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki? Doing so will remove explicit ownership and you will no longer earn reputation for upvotes on it. Once saved, this option cannot be unchecked without moderator assistance.]

Those are the terms & conditions, yours to accept or decline.

---

Now, you asked a bunch of other questions...

> I raised a flag on one of these answers to request that the CW be rolled back, but the flag was declined effectively stating that the request was not worth the moderator's time.

That may be how you *interpreted* it, but here's what your flag said:

> I'm flagging this answer to request that the Community Wiki be removed from this particular answer (it was added in the first place for no real reason)

...and this is what the response said:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Now... You can be forgiven for misunderstanding this, given you didn't know what Community Wiki meant for answers. Hopefully now that I've explained that and shown you the obscure UI that appears to answer authors, it makes a bit more sense.

> So, I ask. Are these markings valid?

Yes. I too would've declined the flag, for the same reason. There's a bunch of discussion below Ry's answer about whether *he should've been the one to decline it*, but that's tangential: your flag would've been declined regardless.

> If not, what is the right thing to do when you come across actions taken by a user whose intentions are not 100% clear?

You can bring it up on meta or flag or both. As you've done; there's absolutely nothing wrong with calling attention to a situation that you don't understand! Just always be willing to accept that you may not have all the information, and approach it with an open mind, willing to learn.

Comment: Much of the cause of my confusion is because of the lack of clarity surrounding the feature to begin with... the guidelines set down by Jeff (the person who introduced the feature) seem to have gone out of fashion now. I guess it is time for me to change my way of thinking. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't know off-hand which guidelines you're referring to there, @coldspeed; as I noted, there is a long and very complicated past to the use of CW, particularly as it pertains to *questions* - many words have been written on that by many people, including Jeff. Answers are much simpler, as marking an answer CW does not affect anyone else's posts.

Comment: So, if an answer gets heavily downvoted, the owner can just mark it a community wiki after the fact, and dodge any rep loss? Sounds a bit strange.

Comment: It's not retroactive, @erik - whatever rep is lost stays lost as long as the post is visible. Yes, you can stave off future rep loss... But you could also just delete the answer, and that would get you back the rep you've already lost too.

Comment: @Shog9 That's true, but it does encourage doing things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790531/7296893): writing up an NAA and marking it community wiki so he can't lose rep. Sometimes, you know an answer won't be received well (e.g. answers on bad questions, opinionated answers with unpopular opinions). Imo we should have _some_ standard for when a CW is appropriate.

Comment: @Shog9, I wrote a question on meta about the same post Erik is referring in his comment here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369307/converting-your-comment-that-is-written-as-answer-to-a-community-wiki-doesnt-wa#comment599133_369307

Comment: See [my answer to Luuklag's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369307/comment-written-as-answer-converted-to-community-wiki-doesnt-warrant-a-custom-f/369335#369335), @Erik; this makes effectively no difference.

Answer (score 20):

There's a few reasons I occasionally use CW, mostly some variant of "I don't *really* deserve the reputation for this":

1. A significant chunk of the answer was informed by someone else's comment
2. The answer is mostly a trivial quote from the documentation (the kind of thing where you think "couldn't OP have looked this up themselves)
3. Occasionally bounty questions, especially where I think the question is a lot simpler than the bounty implies, (I know CW doesn't stop you earning the bounty though...)
4. Sometimes when I have a strong suspicion that the asker is going to be a help vampire and I have no intention of answering follow-up questions. Especially if I'm deliberately posting an outline (enough to set an informed user in the right track) rather than a complete solution that can be wholesale copy-pasted. This is mostly a downvote protection scheme, although actually these rarely actually get downvoted.

I feel option 1 is probably at least "in the spirit" that CW was designed for. Options 2 and 3 are harmless but not quite what it was designed for. I could see option 4 being seen as slightly dodgy (being partly for avoiding downvotes) but on the occasions I've done it I have at least being trying to be helpful, and in my mind it's more about distancing myself from the answer to say "no further support" than it is about a small hypothetical reputation loss.

Comment: Which of the listed categories applies here? :o

Comment: The little-used category 5: "I thought it would be mildly amusing".

Comment: Option 1 (which I've also [used recently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48252437/2)) is *somewhat* in the spirit of community wiki, but not completely. De-repping an answer because we're not its primary author is *part* of community wiki's purpose, but *another* part of its purpose is to invite others to edit the answer. In scenario 1, we want to do the first thing but not the second. But since those two mechanics are coupled to each other; we can't do that, so we have to pick one of two imperfect outcomes.

Comment: (1) @MarkAmery It's a bit of a stretch, but we might further justify #1 by noting that there is less reason to claim ownership of an answer if most of its content is drawn from someone else's posts. (2) DavidW: This is very much a matter of personal opinion, but anyway I don't feel like bothering with #2 and #3. It is true that I have some trivial answers that were highly upvoted, but it is also true that I have some highly non-trivial answers that got low exposure and few upvotes. That being so, I feel things even out in the end.

Comment: This Ans Like ChatGTP

Answer (score 8):

> When is it justified to Community Wiki your own answers?

Er... *whenever you want to*.

There are times when you *should* CW your answers -

- When most of your answer is just a quote or sourced from something else
- When you are posting an answer that was posted as a comment or in the question and the OP of the content is not responding/available/active to do it themselves.
- When the answer is the work of many different people rather than just one person

And more...

...but if there's no reason to, and you just *want* to... then the answer is "whenever you want".

If you're concerned that it prevents reputation loss from downvotes, don't be; it also prevents reputation gain from any upvotes, which is a bigger loss to the poster than it is to the community, downvotes cost the poster 2 rep, and upvotes grant them 10, after all.

Marking posts as Community Wiki also doesn't make it any harder to delete the post if it is of sufficient low quality.

Comment: "There are times when you *should* CW your answers [...] When most of your answer is just a quote or sourced from something else" -- I feel "should" is too strong for this case. Retrieving information from a source (or many of them) that precisely answers a question is not always trivial, and if there is a line behind which such answers don't deserve credit, it is hard to pinpoint where it lies. (It is a different matter if the source is actually a Stack Overflow post or comment, but that is covered by your second bullet point.)

Comment: @duplode By "most", I did mean an overwhelming majority, like a big block quote and a sentence by you saying "here is what I found on X website". If there's substantive work of your own included, then I would probably not say it "should" be CW.

Answer (score 6):

There is one case where making your answers CW is clearly abusive, and that is if you're doing it to avoid the reputation loss for downvotes. As this is about intent, and we can't read the minds of other users, it's a bit more complicated to detect this. But I would in general consider it worthy of moderator intervention if a user posted several CW answers that have a clear negative score recently.

The Community Wiki status is an explicit invitation for other users to edit the post and improve it. That's the primary purpose of it.

Using CW for anything that isn't about inviting actual collaboration on that post is arguably not in the spirit of CW, but then SE itself ignored the spirit of CW with the automatic CW conversion in cases that were meant to punish users and take away their reputation. They finally stopped this in 2014.

I'd probably lean towards not considering heavy use of CW problematic by itself, even if I think it's not the intended use case for it. As long as the posts aren't bad by themselves, it doesn't really do any harm.

These specific cases are in my personal opinion not something the Community Wiki feature should be used for. The answers aren't of a kind that invites collaboration and where CW would be useful. But I also don't see any harm caused here that would warrant overriding the user.

Comment: *had* ignored - it's been a few years since the automatic conversion was removed.

Comment: @BoltClock I clarified that part, it should not have read like this is still happening. I know it's been removed, I wrote the main feature request that asked for automatic CW to be abolished.

Comment: I value your opinion a lot and agree with guidance laid out here, however I would appreciate if you could comment on the specific case the OP brought up as well.