# Comment written as answer converted to community wiki doesn't warrant a custom flag?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags, community-wiki, custom-flags

Today I came over this answer (now deleted) in review: [Import Error: No module named numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy/50790531#50790531) [image: <10k screenshot]  <sup>Screenshot credit to  [Suraj Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj-rao)</sup>

It read as just a comment which was turned into community wiki by its author around the same time that the answer was written, so most likely very intentionally.

I found this behaviour odd, and the only reason I could think of why someone would do this is to avoid the negative consequences a downvoted / removed post has on your reputation / ability to post Q and A's.

So I thought it was best to flag this for moderator attention and used the following text:

> It might be worth teaching this user about community wiki, I think he was trying to avoid consequences by turning his comment posted as answer into a CW.

I found my flag declined, with the (standard) reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

So my question is: **was I wrong in suspecting any dubious behaviour?**

Comment: Moderators can't dispute flags; only mark helpful or decline. Custom mod flags only go to mods.

Comment: @Catija, good to know, changed my text accordingly.

Comment: ask for screenshot and you shall [receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9NWP.png)

Comment: See [Shog's answer on When is it justified to Community Wiki your own answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369210/7296893), and my comments on them. Apparently, this behaviour is perfectly acceptable (aside from the point that NAA answers should be flagged NAA).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth from the screenshot OP must have come across the post in the review queue. Flagging is not really necessary in this case

Comment: don't you need 100 rep to make community wikis? which is higher than the 50 rep comment everywhere, which just confuses me as to why this has occurred at all

Comment: @WhatsThePoint [Its 10 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). You can _edit_ other wiki posts at 100

Comment: @SurajRao another case of where I cant read, imagined a second 0 on the end

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, well I can agree with the point that you can mark an answer CW whenever you wish. However marking an answer CW to avoid any repercussions because you didn't really wrote an answer is a different case IMHO.

Comment: @Luuklag See my comments on that answer. I specifically asked about that, and apparently Shog thinks it's still A-OK.

Comment: Ah I see now, I'll await his reaction on your latest comment. And provide a link to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CW makes zero difference here. The answer was deleted; deleted answers don't count against (or toward) their author's reputation unless they've remained visible on the site for a couple months first - and even then they only count if they're positively scored. So marking a non-answer CW doesn't have any real effect long-term: it just kept the author's reputation from falling by 2 points for a period of 4 hours.

CW also makes no difference in terms of rate-limits or bans: if the majority of your activity on the site is poorly-received, you'll get banned regardless of CW.

Is CW *useful* here? No. Does it cause any problems worth worrying about? Also no.

Comment: Good to know that this method can't be used to game the system. I'll resort to standard flags the next time.