# Is it okay to ask the author of a comment to turn it into an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, unanswered-questions

I feel like this question must have been brought up already but I did not find a duplicate.

I have encountered this kind of situation multiple times. As an example see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120358/how-to-change-text-of-an-label-from-a-custom-class-instantiated-dinamically).

"Mr. Ask" asks a question which is answered by a short comment from "Mr. Comment". "Mr. Browser" sees the question while browsing and notices that there aren't any answers yet so he checks it out. He quickly realizes that the issue is already resolved by a comment and OP has already acknowledged that (e.g. by saying "thank you, it works").

What I thought makes sense until now is this:

- Mr. Ask would ask (by comment): "Could you turn this into an answer so I can mark this question as solved?"
- Mr. Comment would ask (by comment): "Should I turn this into an answer so you can mark this question as solved?"
- Mr. Browser would say (by comment): "@MrComment you should turn this into an answer so OP can accept it."

Is this the right way of doing this?
**How do I act as each of these three people/in these three situations?**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the comment with the solution is recent (which makes the odds of Mx. Comment acting upon it reasonable) it is for Mx. Ask or Mx. Browser to leave *a single* comment suggesting it should be shaped into an answer (no need to insist if someone else has done it already).

[The comment author is not obliged to take up your invitation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339396/2751851); however, there is always the option of [converting the comment into an answer yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/2751851) -- just be sure to include proper attribution to the comment author, and [mark it as Community Wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343086/2751851).

As for Mx. Comment themselves asking whether they should turn the comment into an answer, that shouldn't be necessary. If the solution is correct and addresses the question, there is no reason not to make it into an answer.