# Can we make posting a question with an answer easier?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, instant-self-answer

As a developer I learn some really random ins and outs of various tools and libraries that I use on a daily basis. I often want to document, those stupid little things that cost me 4 hours to figure out. Looking at you Typescript compiler options.

I am bad at managing my own notes and documentation with tools like OneNote, EverNote, etc. Enterprise solutions are generally painful and I lose access if I change jobs. I am lazy and I don't want to maintain a blog.

If I run into an issue again I am probably going to search Stack Overflow anyways to see if I get a quick hit. So it seems like I should be posting a question and answer for my own self interest.

There seems to be a couple discussions here on the Meta site saying "yes answering your own questions is encouraged but make sure you do it well and watch out for all this stuff."

[How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)

[Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Could we make it so that "make sure you do it well and watch out for this stuff" is easier? Should Stack Overflow have a template for putting a posting a question and answer together? Maybe prevent or decrease the rep from begin gained on self answered questions?

Comment: Self Answer are just normal question and normal answer, most of the time people wont notice the self answer. But be carefull, StackOverflow is not Blog oriented. That's why many StackOverflow question ends up into Blog post but not the contrary.

Comment: If you think the information will be useful to someone else, I think self-answering makes sense, especially if it wasn't easy to find. That's especially true if you find yourself looking for the same information over and over. I did that once because even the documentation was vague. The reaction was slightly more negative than positive, but I don't care. I couldn't easily google the answer, and now I can.

Comment: Btw, make sure to make it a community wiki!

Comment: "*Could we make it so that "make sure you do it well and watch out for this stuff" is easier?*" easier in what way? Making quality content is not an automated or automatable process. Not easily, at least. "*Should Stack Overflow have a template for putting a posting a question and answer together?*" it does - go to Ask Question and tick the box that says **Answer your own question**. It even includes a link to [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You can now put question and answer at the same time and post them together.

Comment: @Lighteninger I would advise against that as a general rule. Only mark it as Community Wiki if you have [a good reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343086/2751851) for disclaiming authorship.

Comment: @Lighteninger CW is for posts that are collaborative works of multiple people.  This doesn't sound like a collaborative work of multiple people.

Comment: Fine I understand, thanks for correcting my views for CW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could we make it so that "make sure you do it well and watch out for this stuff" is easier?

Not really.  This stems from the fact that *asking good questions is inherently hard to do*.  Ensuring a question is clear, appropriately scoped, on topic, well researched, objective, concise, about a useful topic, and so on, is not easy.  Writing an answer that's understandable, clearly correct, concise, and so on, is *also* not easy.

Posting a self answered question is not hard from the perspective of the technical operations you need to perform on the site to post such content.  It's just hard to do *well* because writing good questions and good answers is hard.  Many people also find it harder to write a good question when they know the answer, rather than when they don't.

So there isn't really much that the site can do to help make this any easier, beyond what they can do to make it easier for *anyone* to ask *any* question well.

Comment: Realistically from technical point of view I can't even see how to make that easier than it is already - SO already gives one chance to post question + self-answer on the same page with single "Post Your Question And Answer" button...

Answer (score 6):

I do not think that answering your own question should be any different from answering a other persons question.

In both cases the asker (you) and the answerer (also you) should try to provide a clear question and a good answer, on both of which resources are available if you want to find out how to do so:

See help for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

> Maybe prevent or decrease the rep from begin gained on self answered
>   questions?

You already do not gain any reputation for accepting your own answer. As for the votes gained from other members of the community I don't think that they should be less valuable and therefore result in less reputation rewarded than answers from other users.